# URL to perform Google Image Search for a specific URL

Tags: google-image-search

It used to be possible to perform an image search using the following URL format:

`https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=<URLHERE>`

But it seems to no longer be functional.

Did it change to something else or is Google no longer offering this functionality?

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+site:stackoverflow.com&tbm=isch

`site:` prefix is available on the google search.

Comment: That does a keyword-based query, what I want is a URL-based query (provide a URL to search for visually similar images).